# Apt-mirror key question

Tags: software-installation, offline, apt-mirror, pgp

Before downloading PPAs with apt-mirror I need to have the PPA GPG key installed in my key ring, e.g. by using the command

```
 add-apt-repository ppa:something/ppa
```

After this (and editing mirror.list) apt-mirror downloads the PPA files to a local repository. Apt-mirror does not seem to include the keys into the local archive.

Are the PPA keys also required when installing directly from the lokal (mirrored) repository?

Comment: seems I keep asking the wrong questions for this forum. I am not aware of an alternative Q/A like site for a bit more complex ubuntu issues. Would be glad to lean of any, though.

Comment: You can find more complex issues and thread-based (instead of question-based) official support at http://ubuntuforums.org

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found out in the mean time. The answer is, that the keys must be copied with the closed repository to the offline site. Otherwise `apt-get update` will not access the files and throw errors.

The keys do not have to be stored with the offline repository, though. They may be stored anywhere, e.g. a central file server, NAS etc. The keys must be copied to every offline computer that wants to install from the offline archive.
For example, the keys are stored in a local samba share *smb://PPA-Keys* that was mounted to */mnt/test* on a new computer. This would copy the keys to the required location

```
sudo cp /mnt/test/*.gpg /etc/apt/trusted.d/
```

The main issue is, however, to get the keys in the first place. By adding the repository with `add-apt-repository` the process is easy. The key should be placed in the folder `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/` so just collect it there.

Example

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa
 cp /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/libreoffice_ubuntu_ppa.gpg /mnt/test/libreoffice.gpg
```

If there is no key at that location it had been added to the general keychain in `trusted.gpg`. Instead of extracting it from there it is easier to download the key from the PPA site manually. The download is only a textfile (*.key or *.asc), so we need to convert it to a binary gpg key. The example assumes that the text key is in the file `libreoffice.asc`

Example

```
 cat libreoffice.asc | gpg -deamor > libreoffice.gpg
```

The keys for the Ubuntu repository are in the `/etc/apt/trused.gpg` file. If they are lost or broken, just copy that file from another machine or a fresh installation.